# Avoid app and user limit on private APP

Tags: facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am starting with Facebook Marketing API as I need to automatize my Facebook Campaigns. The problem is that I have a lot of adsets so I am reaching the app limit and the user limit very easily. I have read a lot about this and it seems that I have to upgrade my app from "development" to "Basic". Is that true?
How can I do that? It seems that I need to submit my app for approval but to do that the app needs to be public with a login... is that true? But why do I need that if I only need to access the API for private use? What can I do here?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Having an app in public mode doesn't mean anyone can just login to the app. It just means the app is not in development mode.

If you use that is not public, you will also find that you cannot perform some actions against the Ads API.

The developer tier of the Marketing API is there to just start developing while making sure you're not doing something that consumes more resources than you need.